# Javascript Refresh Event Handlers While Mouse Button is Down

Tags: javascript

Apparently (at least in firefox) when the mouse is down, event handlers cannot be refreshed. I am attempting to write some drag and drop code and when the element is being dragged, I would like to be able to tell which element it is "touching" using the mouseover event handlers, but this doesn't work. Is there a way to enable this, or a workaround?

Comment: Code should not be needed. Basically, when I have the mouse button down, my event handlers cannot be refreshed, so if I have a loop that adds a handler to a list of items, only the first in the list will be available.